# Return entries where field is "not empty"

Tags: entries, error-message

I'm trying to return entries where a specific field named "productSale" is not empty. Unfortunately, my code attempts keep throwing the "Expected name or number" error.

Code attempts include:

```
{% set products = craft.entries.section('product').productSale.(':notempty:').find() %}
{% set products = craft.entries.section('product').productSale.('not null').find() %}
{% set products = craft.entries.section('product').productSale.('is not null').find() %}
{% set products = craft.entries.section('product').productSale.('not empty').find() %}
```

Three questions then:

1. What is the "Expected name or number" error saying exactly?
2. Where in the available docs (Craft or Twig) would I look for explanation on this? I didn't find much in my first pass.
3. How do I return entries where a specific field is "not empty"

Comment: Try removing the dot after productSale: productSale(':notempty:')

Comment: Do you know where in the docs I can find ":notempty:"?

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll added it as an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**1. "Expected name or number" error**

The parser is expecting a method/property after the dot of `productSale`, but you are passing arguments. Removing the dot to make it valid:

```
{% set products = craft.entries.section('product').productSale(':notempty:') %}
```

.

**2. Documentation**

There is no documentation on this yet, but it is listed in the [release notes](https://craftcms.com/changelog#2-0-2524):

> Added support for passing “:empty:” and “:notempty:” to
>   [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) parameters when you’re looking for
>   empty/non-empty values.