# How to check custom field not empty within params?

Tags: entries, custom-field, params

The following returns entries correctly:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('sectionName').customField(':notempty:').limit(10) as products %}
    {% for product in products %}
        {% include 'incs/_productSnippet' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

But the following returns empty:

```
{% set params = { section: 'sectionName', customField: ':notempty', limit: 10} %}
{% paginate craft.entries(params) as products %}
    {% for product in products %}
        {% include 'incs/_productSnippet' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

It's the latter I'm after because the customField I want to check varies. Removing the `customField: ':notempty',` from `params` in the second example returns entries, so I'm guessing it's the way I'm using customField within `params`?

Comment: Seems you're missing the closing colon `:notempty:` in the 2nd example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re just missing the `:` at the end of `:notempty:` in your second example. This will work:

```
{% set params = { section: 'sectionName', customField: ':notempty:', limit: 10} %}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any documentation on this? Similar example here: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/452/return-entries-where-field-is-not-empty