# Show a quote on my login page

Tags: filter, table-field

I have a number of entries, each with a quote (table field with one phrase and author row). I would like to show one quote on my login page, but some of these entries do not have quotes.

How can i filter the entries so that it can only choose from the entries that have quotes and exclude the ones who don't have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to retrieve all entries where a certain field is not empty?

[Return entries where field is "not empty"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/452/return-entries-where-field-is-not-empty)