# Eagerload inverse relation

Tags: relations, eager-loading

I would like to eagerload inverse relation. Business case:
I have stories, stories are connected to books over relatedBooks field. Now I would like to query those books only which not have any story.

I do not see any easy way to do it, so I thought that to using eagerload the related stories somehow, and filtering out the nulls
What also could help is to just using having count somehow

But I am not able to do it, because I am not able to lead the relatedBooks(inverse) from books perspective, only from stories.

Tried to use the manyToMany plugin, but it is not helping either, just giving a nice interface

Also I know I can query one-by-one but that is silly

(last workaround would be to use hardcoded sql, but I would like to avoid this one:) )

Comment: With eagerloading, you're referring to https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html right?

Comment: Is this roughly the same question as https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/10456/8325 ? (it has no accepted answer though)

Comment: Also, you might want to post your current code sample

Comment: It sounds like you don't need "eager loading." That's a work-around for slow performance issues. You are trying to find entries in a "Books" section that have no relationships to entries in a "Stories" section. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

in this case you should use `:empty:`, like this:

`{% set orphanBooks = craft.entries.section('books').relatedStories(':empty:') %}`

**ORIGINAL CONTENT**

According to the documentation, you can query the entries using your field handle:

> TIP
>
> Most custom fields support element query parameters as well, named
>   after the field handles.

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/#executing-element-queries

You might use `:notempty:` as a negative selector, just like in this query:

`{% set products = craft.entries.section('product').productSale(':notempty:') %}`

These SE question and answers might be helpful, too:

[Get entries NOT related to categories](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10456/get-entries-not-related-to-categories)

[Return entries where field is "not empty"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/452/return-entries-where-field-is-not-empty)

Comment: With your code, you would finde products without a `productSale`. What the OP wants is `productSale`s that haven't been related to a product (orphans)

Comment: Yep, you are right: updated my answer.

Comment: This will return a list of all books, as no book has a field "relatedStories". The relation is the other way round (inverse).

Comment: Well, yeah. In this case Many to Many Field Type might be useful: https://github.com/page-8/craft-manytomany